# Automatically generate bugs item in Azure boards when hits an exception in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-boards

I am trying to create a bug item in azure boards whenever the application hits performance issue or exceptions via azure application insights. I searched few articles, but none of them were pointing how we enable it on the fly. Not sure if the feature exists in app insights. Any advise or pointers shared would be much appreciated in this case.

Thanks Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, [unfortunately automatically creating work items](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/15301740-ability-to-create-automatically-manually-work-item) has not been implemented and is still in the backlog. But, You can absolutely create work items from Failures using Application Insights

**`Summarized steps:`**

1. Navigate to your Application Insights resource Click on Failures
2. (under Investigate) to list exceptions
3. Click on an exception to get to the End-to-end transaction details page Click on
4. +Create work item in the upper right and complete the wizard

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for the valuable input. Let me try to setup the failure scenario and revert back if any obstacles. Thanks again.